# Android root poweroff

Tags: android, root, shutdown

On my android app for root user, I perform a shutdown with

```
su reboot -p
```

It works ok, but I noticed that the phone is shutdown almost instantly (as opposed from showing the shutdown animation, and probably doing other stuff).

Is this the correct way to shutdown an android phone programmatically? Are there some critical code that requires to be executed before shutdown?

Comment: @unforgettableid your proposed edit is both seriously mistaken (apps can never run as root, only at most native helpers), and relatively pointless as this is a 4-year old question of low value that doesn't need to be revisited.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Thank you for correcting me; I've revised my edit suggestion. A GitHub commenter just referenced this Stack Overflow thread in a [GitHub comment](https://github.com/ppareit/Shutdown/issues/4#issuecomment-188899438) this past February.  I agree that it was silly for the GitHub commenter to reference such an ancient thread.  Still, he did reference it.  Because the answers were so old, someone else wasted their time doing a suboptimal commit to an open-source project.

Comment: @ChrisStratton:  I did a Google search but could find no newer thread which mentions the `svc power shutdown` solution.  If there such a thread does come to exist in the future, we should flag this ancient thread as a duplicate of that newer thread.  It's too bad that Google seems to give such high search-results rankings to Stack Overflow threads so ancient.  Perhaps we could somehow add some stale-content warning at the top.  Or, better yet, perhaps we should just flag outdated questions as duplicates of newer identical questions.

Comment: Your revised edit still changes the question away from what was asked.  Also, there is no such thing as "root privileges" in "Android" - that only exists in non-standard ways in various modified systems, so forcing it into the title is just a distraction from the subject.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: 1. Even if the user has kludged a non-standard hack such as SuperSU into `/system`, most people would still call the OS "Android", even though it's no longer quite the same as what Google shipped. This is because it still looks and feels and works so much like true Android. 2. Summaries tend to be imperfect. I still think that my new title summarizes the question better than the original title. Do you agree? 3. Can you propose a title which is even better than the one I have proposed?

Comment: The original title was more accurate and to the point, and avoids drudging a 4 year old low quality question back to the top of the homepage to accomplish nothing but a distortion of the asker's intent which will only need to be reverted again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Android source code, you can find the following:

```
/**
 * Low-level function turn the device off immediately, without trying
 * to be clean.  Most people should use
 * {@link android.internal.app.ShutdownThread} for a clean shutdown.
 *
 * @deprecated
 * @hide
 */
@Deprecated
public static native void shutdown();
```

I think that this native function corresponds to your `su reboot -p`. Moreover, you can see from the quoted code comment that you should use ShutdownThread to do a clean shutdown.

In ShutdownThread, Android does a bunch of things.

- It shuts down ActivityManager.  I think shutting down ActivityManager means that all activities will pass necessary lifecycle and, thus, the states of activities will be stored.  But I'm not sure.  I did not check.
- Then, Android turns off the cellular radio interface.
- After that, it turns off Bluetooth.
- Finally, it tries to shut MountService down.

Thus, you can see that it's wrong to do `su reboot -p`.

Comment: You've just asked if yours approach is right. I showed you why it's not a good practice to do so. I did not tell you that 'shutdown()' method will work in your case.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, however my question implied "what should be the best practice to shutdown?", but no one is able to answer that question... :(

Comment: Actually, this is the best practice. But you can use it only if you have the certificate. If you do not a user should use power button to shutdown the device, so there should be explicit user's consent to shutdown the device. In other case malicious applications can shutdown the phone without user's permission.

Comment: No 3rd-party application code has the authority to use this method.

Answer (score 2):

## On Android 4.3 or later, there's probably a better way to shut the device down.

Your app doesn't need to be installed as a system app, but it must have root privileges.  You can simply run this one command as root in order to shut the device down:

`svc power shutdown`

I thank Firelord for his answer [elsewhere](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43706/whats-the-best-way-to-restart-android-via-command-line-remotely#139139) which inspired me to discover the existence of this shell command.

I think this will do a graceful shutdown, but I'm not sure.  Maybe it will do an abrupt shutdown.  Please test, and then [edit this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37647989/edit) to clarify.

Also, the above shell command does not work in Android 4.2.2 or earlier.  The [help text](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.2.2_r1.2/cmds/svc/src/com/android/commands/svc/PowerCommand.java#35) doesn't mention it.  `svc` rejects the command as invalid and shows some help text in order to try to be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If your app is rooted, then run the following as root:

`am start -a android.intent.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN`

Answer (score 0):

See here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
pm.reboot("Because I want you to reboot!")
```

<strike>This should work.</strike>

Comment: Sorry, I just found out, that it only works for app that are signed as "system apps" instead of user apps. (It is only possible if you know the key the firmware was signed with)

Comment: This will not work, as no 3rd party application has the authority to do this.