# Android device shutdown - want "ShutdownThread->shutdown()"not "su reboot -p"

Tags: android, shutdown, android-permissions

Several questions about shutting down a rooted android device have answers saying you should run "reboot -p" within an "su" shell.  However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598522/android-root-poweroff/9600769) says that reboot is quite low-and-dirty and doesn't do sufficient tidying up before pulling the plug.  Instead it recommends using `android.internal.app.ShutdownThread.shutdown()`. Looking at [the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/com/android/internal/app/ShutdownThread.java#ShutdownThread.shutdown%28android.content.Context,boolean%29) I can see that this does a whole bunch of housekeeping stuff that I'd like to have, and it also has a handy "confirm" parameter that appears to let you shut down without asking for confirmation, which is nice.

My question is this - what properties does an app have to have in order to call `ShutdownThread.shutdown()`?  Does is require a particular permission that can be set if the device is rooted, or does it have to be signed using the firmware key, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shutting down the device requires you to hold `android.permission.SHUTDOWN` which is only available to system applications, or applications signed with the platform certificate.

Comment: Thanks.  I recently discovered this via a separate route, but you get the credit for telling me here!